# How to insert/add logo before the top navigation in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Is there a way to insert/add logo  before the top navigation in SharePoint ? Currently we have Home link and we want to replace it using a logo instead.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assume you are talking about SharePoint online development. I suggest using **command set** in **SharePoint Framework**.

The **Command Set** is the only type of SharePoint Framework Extension for which you can configure icons.

When deploying Command Sets, you can choose whether their commands should be visible on:

The command bar (`location: ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.CommandBar`)

The context menu (`location: ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.ContextMenu`)

Both (`location: ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet`)

You can use an external icon image or a base64-encoded image as your icon image.

[image]

References form [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/basics/configure-extension-icon)

Also, there is a third party option. it will be less work just to change a icon but also limited choice of icons which they've provided.

**ShortPoint** can customize SharePoint Global Navigation and allows you to utilize ShortPoint Icons in your navigation.

The result will be something like this. Reference [here](https://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000261044-how-to-use-shortpoint-icons-in-the-sharepoint-global-navigation).
[image]

So depend on your need, SPFx will give you more freedom and Shortpoint will take less work.

As for SharePoint On-premises. I think these below links can help you.

**Customizing SharePoint 2010 global navigation with** Css and jQuery [Link](https://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/customizing-sharepoint-2010-global-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-2/)

**Top Navigation By Ryan Keller** [Link](https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/branding-top-navigation-in-sharepoint-2013)

**Customize the navigation on your SharePoint site** [Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca)

Hope this can help you.